# javascript accordion / css not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress-theming, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a blog page on which I have to list the posts using an accordion jQuery. I managed to get it to work but it's not rendering properly, more precisely: the height of the page does not enlarge accordingly to the post size. You can see it here: http://melisayavas.com/web/?page_id=22

I think this is more a CSS problem than a jQuery, unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge of CSS or jQuery to actually be sure where the problem is and how to fix it.

This is the HTML & JS of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#va-accordion').vaccordion();
        });

    </script>


<div id="va-accordion" class="va-container">
<div class="va-wrapper">
<div class="about-page">    
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'About', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="va-slice">
    <article class="about" id="about-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="title"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></div>
        <div class="va-content">
        <div class="entry">
            <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
        </div>
        </div>

        <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

    </article>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I used:

```
/* Vertical Accordion Style */
.va-container{
position:relative;
}
.va-wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background:#000;
}
.va-slice{
cursor:pointer;
width:100%;
left:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.va-title{
}
.va-content{
display:none;
margin-left:25px;
}
.va-slice p{
}
.va-slice ul{
margin-top:20px;
}
.va-slice ul li{
}
.va-slice ul li a{
}
.va-slice ul li a:hover{
}

.post {
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 10px;
clear: both; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding: 20px;
margin-top: 28px;
}

.about {
clear: both; 
overflow: hidden; 
}

.about-page {
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 10px;
clear: both; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding: 20px;
margin-top: 28px;
}
```

The full accordion jQuery can be found here: http://pastebin.com/hJEufLQU

Comment: In `jquery.vaccordion.js` try changing the heights of `accordionH` (line 300) and `expandedHeight` (line 305) to `auto` (they are currently `450`/`350` respectively)

Comment: The `auto` didn't do anything and the script stopped working. Now I'm thinking of adding a fixed height and a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: What happens if you delete these lines (300/305) completely?

Comment: No problem - I have added it as an answer for you

Comment: Any idea how I can make the first element to auto-expand when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `jquery.vaccordion.js` the height of the accordion element and height of expanded accordion items are being set explicilty:

```
line 300 - accordionH : 450
... 
line 305 - expandedHeight: 350
```

Because of this, the elements are too small to fit the post content. You can either try removing these lines or setting their heights to `"auto"`.

**Edit**

To answer your addittional comment "*Any idea how I can make the first element to auto-expand when the page loads?*"

It looks to me like accordion should handle this behavour by default [[see accordion demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)]. So I am not sure why it is not showing the first element. Anyway, you can resolve this via CSS:

```
#va-accordion .va-slice:first-child .va-content{
    display: block;       
}
```

**JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mcDeE/**

Comment: Actually it worked simply by replacing the explicit values with `'auto'` - just like you said. Thanks, again!

Comment: @GeorgeGrigorita - thanks, I have updated my answer. I have also added some information about displaying the first element on page load.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.va-slice').click(function(){
                    var index_div = $(this).index();
                    var element = $('.va-slice').eq(index_div);
                }); 
    });
</script>
```

Apply the script which add a class 'explicit_va' on that element

```
    .explicit_va{
        min-height:0px !important;
        height:100% !important;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the previous user's solution was easier (at least for me to understand it) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.va-slice').click(function(){
                var index_div = $(this).index();
                //console.log(index_div);

                var element = $('.va-slice').eq(index_div);
                //console.log(element);
                //var getHeight = element.height();
                //console.log(getHeight);

                console.log(element.attr('style', ''));         
                console.log(element.addClass('explicit_va'));

            }); 
});
</script>
```

More : http://source88.blogspot.com/search/label/Accordion